# jQuery Validate plugin - display error message only if specific message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'd like to display error message only if it's a specific message.
If the error text is not the one I expect, it will not be displayed.

Here is my code:

```
rules: {
        telephone: {
            required: true,
            phoneFR: true,
            remote: {
                  url: 'validate_customer.php',
                  type: "post",
                  data: {
                      telephone: function() {
                          return $('#new-customer-formulaire :input[name="telephone"]').val();
                      },
                      nom: function() {
                          return $('#new-customer-formulaire :input[name="nom"]').val();
                      },
                      prenom: function() {
                          return $('#new-customer-formulaire :input[name="prenom"]').val();
                      }
                  }
              }
        }       
},
messages: {
        telephone: {
            remote: "Un client existe déjà dans la base avec le même nom, prénom et n° de téléphone."
        }
},
errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
         if (error.prop("textContent") == "Un client existe déjà dans la base avec le même nom, prénom et n° de téléphone.") error.insertAfter(element);
         else return true;          
      },
```

### The problem is that

if the remote message appears first (so if an user with same first name, last name and phone number already exists in the database), it shows the message for the required and phoneFR rules after. But I would like to prevent it, and only show the message for the remote rule

Comment: This would be handled within your server-side script, `validate_customer.php`.  Instead of echoing a true/false, echo a JSON encoded string that contains the relevant message.  Echo true when you want the rule to pass.

Comment: The last part does not make sense.  If the field is filled out so that the `remote` rule is activated, then the `required` rule will never come into play.  If the field is empty, the `required` rule is going to tell the user to fill that out... you cannot bypass `required` message without disabling the `required` rule, otherwise, what's the point.  If you want messages from only the `remote` rule, then you need to remove all other rules from this field.